# How to insert row number in database in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to insert ROW NUMBER inside table through controller but failed,
I have tried something like this but showing error,

```
$data = array(
            'name'=>$request->name, 'email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$password, 'status'=>1, 'user_id' =>ROW_NUMBER()
        );
```

I just want to insert ROW NUMBER of table inside `user_id`.
Also, if not possible can we insert unique serial number inside `user_id`

Please help me out.

Comment: in `user_id` field you want to insert `id` of special `User`. RIGHT???

Comment: I just want to insert a unique id in it,

Comment: in all tables in DB is a field name `id` that is `primary key` and `Auto increment` that mean it's unique in this table, in `Users_tbl` you have the `id` field, if you want to use it (because you have written `user_id`) you can use `id` of `User_tbl` that is unique

Comment: I have already 'id' field with AUTO INCREMENT and PRIMARY KEY in my table. I have another field i.e. 'user_id' I just want to add unique id inside it also. It may be row number or serial number

Comment: so you can use `count($your_model_tbl::all())`, it's like RowNumber

Comment: $your_model_tbl will contain my table name ??

Comment: yes, you can use this code `\DB::table('table_name')->count();`

Comment: it works, thanks a lot dude,

Comment: you're welcome, thanks god.

Comment: using `count()` is not good, it has the same problem I explained in the answer section. @Rezash

Answer (score 1):

Each row has a column with name 'id' that is **unique** and **Auto increment**.

You can pass 'id' value to 'user_id' like below: (but it's not a good idea)

**Why it is a bad idea?**

Because when you delete your last row (assume id is **5**) your next record 'id' is **6** but the user_id that will you retrieve with code below will be **5**.
So, use the alternate option that I will give you in the following.

```
$last_user = User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
$new_user = new User;
...
$new_user->user_id = $last_user->id + 1 ;
$new_user->save();
```

I figure it out from comments that you need a unique id and this your idea to solve this problem.
I have a better idea and hope that will help you.

you can use `uniqid()` method.

```
$new_user = new User;
...
$new_user->user_id = uniqid();
$new_user->save();
```